# Firestore queries with condition

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want to compare the project id in firestore and my id from props and get all the data from this collection.

I have this structure

[image]

```js
export const getProjData = data => async(dispatch, getState,{firebase,firestore}) => {
  
  const { uid: userId } = getState().firebase.auth;
    try{
  
      const res = await firestore.collection("Projects").doc(userId).where("id","==",data).get()
      console.log(res)

    } catch(err) {
  
    }
 }
```

But i get undefined

Comment: Trying to add a subcollection, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id field you're trying to query exists inside of an array type field at element 0.  You won't be able to query for it, if that's how you need to store the data.  Cloud Firestore just don't have a type of query that can look inside of maps of array type fields.

You're going to have to restructure your data.  If you find yourself needing to query items of arrays, that probably means your array needs to be split up into documents of a nested subcollection.

Comment: I want the user to have many projects. How then to store the data?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you will want to move the array items to a subcollection.

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea? What's your objection?

Comment: Please don't rewrite questions if you have a new question.  This invalidates all answers and can be confusing to people.  I rolled back your edit so that the original question is answered correctly by the answer I've given here, since this information might be helpful for others in the future.  If you have a new problem with new code you've written, please post that as a whole new question.